# cant access class variable from class function

Tags: c++, class, non-static

i created a header Persona.h and in Persona.cc i am initializing all the variables and functions of the class, why can't i access a variable from Persona.cc?

Persona.h

```
#ifndef STD_LIB_H
#include <iostream>
#endif
#ifndef STD_LIB_H
#include <string>
#endif

class Persona
{
    private:
        std::string Nome;

    public:
        Nasci(std::string);
};
```

Persona.cc

```
#ifndef Persona_h
#include "Persona.h"
#endif

#ifndef STD_LIB_H
#include <string>
#endif

void Persona::Nasci(std::string nome)
{
    // Nome della persona

    Nome = nome;
};
```

it gives me an error:

```
invalid use of non-static data member 'Persona::Nome'
```

i can't figure out what to do, can you?

Thank You.

Comment: It's marked `private`, what do you expect?

Comment: Plese get [a book from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). You are only going to badly hurt yourself if you continue without getting the basics right.

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is without some more context, but try changing the method declaration to `Persona::Nasci`. Otherwise, the compiler has no way of knowing that the function is a method of `Persona`.

Comment: @DomeWTF: "... from class function"? You don't have a "class function". You have a completely independent, unrelated, standalone function `Nasci`, which has absolutely nothing to do with the class. That's the first problem.

Comment: `#ifndef Persona_h
#include "Persona.h"
#endif

#ifndef STD_LIB_H
#include <string>
#endif
` No no no. This logic goes *in* the header, the includer should not have to track this stuff. It's fine to include `<string>` as many times as you wanted, don't clutter your code like that. And your header file should wrap itself in the include guards, and the includer simply includes it.

Comment: it gives me multiple definition of Persona::Nasci()

Comment: You've substantially changed the code in your question after all these people commented, which isn't cool. The latest problem I see is that you're using different case in the `.h` and `.cc` files: `nasci` vs. `Nasci`.

Comment: i changed the code to show how it really was on my pc since someone didn't get what it really was

Comment: oh i see what you mean, sorry i just copied it wrong on the forum

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming `Nasci` is a method of `Persona`, and therefore your method definition should look like the following:

```
void Persona::Nasci(std::string nome)
{
    // Nome della persona
    Nome = nome;

    //...rest of the function
}
```

Otherwise, if `Nasci` is not a method or friend function of the `Persona` class-type, you cannot access a private data member of the `Persona` class inside the function body even though you've attempted to use namespace-scope resolution.

Typically when you see code that uses namespace scope resolution on a data-object or function inside another stand-alone function body like you've done, that data-member or function is a non-private `static` method or data-member of a specific class, and therefore is visible to other non-class functions.  Of course there's a number of other uses for the scope resolution operator in C++, but just saying that in your case it would require `Nome` to be a non-private `static` data-member to avoid a compiler error.  Of course using `Nome` in that way wouldn't fit your use scenario though, so what you're really wanting is the above code segment where you designate `Nasci` as a method of `Persona`.

Comment: You'd also have to add the declaration for Nasci to the Persona class.

Comment: Since the OP didn't complete the declaration of the class (i.e., there's no closing bracket on the class declaraion), I'm assuming that `Nasci` is a method of the class they simply decided not to list for the sake of brevity rather than accidental omission.  But yes, if they didn't include the declaration of `Nasci` in the class declaration, they would have to-do that as well.